# figuring out continuity from an ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta

I don't understand how it is possible to decide whether some function $y$ in a certain ODE involving dirac's delta and heaviside function is continuous without solving for y. Say for example:

$y'' +y' + y= (x-1)(\delta(x-3) + H(x-5) + H(x-1))$

I know it is possible to just solve for y using laplace transform, but I understood it is possible to know continuity for $y,y',y''$ just by looking at the expression. I will be really glad for help, I feel like I lack some basic understanding of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ satisfies the ODE then we need $y'$ and $y''$ to exist, so $y$ and $y'$ must be differentiable and hence continuous.  I don't think that $y''$ will be continuous, though, because the sum of continuous functions is continuous and the right hand side of the equation is not continuous.

Comment: Thank you, but if I'm not mistaken, $y'$ has a "jump" in $x=3$. How does that go hand in hand with what you have written? How do I decide where there is a jump for each function if there is indeed a discontinuity? I fail to follow the logic.